# Chrome Context menu is generating incorrect link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I have written a context menu code similar to Google's `Search in Google for '...'`

The code is working fine up to showing menu option and clicking. After selecting the menu option, new tab is created but Chrome tries to load `chrome-extension://acpffpbkehpfofhgilcophibgbkhmmba/https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Wikipedia` instead of `https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Wikipedia`.

Please suggest what could be the problem. Related code is as follows.

```
    function GoogleSearch(info, tab) {
        console.log("Search Google for " + info.selectionText);
        chrome.tabs.create({ 
            url: "www.google.co.in/search?q=" + info.selectionText,
        })
     }

cmid = chrome.contextMenus.create({ 
                                'title': "Search Google for '%s'", 
                                "contexts": ["selection"],
                                'onclick': GoogleSearch
                                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the protocol you want to use in your *URL*

```
chrome.tabs.create({ 
    url: "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" + info.selectionText,
}); //    ^^^^^^^^
```

You will encounter the same behaviour on `<a>` if you don't define a protocol (or start the *URI* with `//` which would mean "use the same protocol as we're on now"). This is expected behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

```
var onRequest = function (i, t, u) {
        var buzz = encodeURI(u + i.selectionText);
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: buzz
        });
    },
    createContext = function (t, call) {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            title: t,
            contexts: ["selection"],
            onclick: call
        }, function () {

        });
    },
    run = function (t, u) {
        createContext(t, function (i, b) {
            onRequest(i, b, u);
        });
    };
run("Search Google for : \"%s\"", "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=");
```